# Reassign key bindings in emacs to run cscope

Tags: emacs, cscope

I'm trying to install xcscope for xemacs on my linux machine at work. Unfortunately emacs is pre-configured to install some of my work related .el files. 
Because of this the "C-c s" prefix doesnt work for cscope, since its bound to printing my company logo.

I have currently put `(define-key global-map "\C-cs" nil)` so that it atleast doesn't print my company logo. But when I try to use it for any cscope commands it doesn't do anything.

This is a copy of my .emacs file:

```
(load-library "Company_XXXXX")
(define-key global-map "\C-cs" nil)
(load-file "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/xcscope.el")
(require 'xcscope)
```

I tried to check the reverse so when I do a "C-h w: cscope-find-this-file" to check what its bound to, it keeps telling me "cscope-find-this-file is not on any key".

Is there any way in which i can tell emacs to bind "C-c s" to cscope ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the minor-mode?  M-x cscope-minor-mode

The library adds some hooks to enable the minor-mode but it's not clear where you are trying to run this.  Also, this has nothing to do with your global-map.  The minor-mode should override the global binding.

Comment: I don't get that option only. When I try to type M-x cscope-minor-mode it says there is no match.